# conflict between mongo find and aggregate results

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose

I have this aggregate query that I am trying to execute

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "restaurantId": 138,
            "createdAt": {
                "$lte": "2016-08-27 23:59:59",
                "$gte": "2016-08-19"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "null",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
]
```

and normal find query

```
{
    "restaurantId": 138,
    "createdAt": {
        "$lte": "2016-08-27 23:59:59",
        "$gte": "2016-08-19"
    }
}
```

This find query gets me the desired result. but aggregate query gives me `[]`
and in database date is stored in this format: `ISODate("2016-08-26T08:19:21.883+0000")`

This is how I am generating date string

```
filter.query.createdAt = {
                    "$lte": moment(Number(data.createdAt.to)).format("YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59"),
                    "$gte": moment(Number(data.createdAt.from)).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                };
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "$gte": "2016-08-19" should be with time as ""$gte": "2016-08-19 00:00:00""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you have currently is comparing the stored dates with strings, you need to create date object representations from the strings in order for the query to work. Use the native JS **[`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** constructor to create a date instance:

```
var end = new Date("2016-08-27 23:59:59"),
    start = new Date("2016-08-19");

var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "restaurantId": 138,
            "createdAt": { "$lte": end, "$gte": start }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
]
```

For more details on dealing with dates in MongoDB, refer to the **[docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#date)**, but in a nutshell:

> The mongo shell provides various methods to return the date, either as
>   a string or as a Date object:
>
> - **`Date()`** method which returns the current date as a string.
> - **`new Date()`**
>     constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.
> - **`ISODate()`** constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate()
>     wrapper.
>
> Internally, Date objects are stored as a 64 bit integer
>   representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1,
>   1970), which results in a representable date range of about 290
>   millions years into the past and future.

---

If you are using the momentjs library, use the **[`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/)** extension method to return the date objects:

```
var end = moment(Number(data.createdAt.to)).toDate(),
    start =  moment(Number(data.createdAt.from)).toDate();
```

To append 23:59:59 to the date, you can use the [**`startOf()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [**`endOf()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) methods on the moment's date object, passing the string `'day'` as arguments:

```
var start = moment(Number(data.createdAt.from)).startOf('day').toDate(); // set to 12:00 am for that date
var end = moment(Number(data.createdAt.to)).endOf('day').toDate(); // set to 23:59 pm for that date
```

Comment: Added in question how I am generating date string.

Comment: You need to call `.toDate()` on a moment object to return a JavaScript Date object which is valid for serialization

Comment: But I need to append 23:59:59 to the date that I am getting in request.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the appropriate methods to use should you want to get the times appended.